# Android: Replace sub fragment with it's parent fragment in main activity container

Tags: android, android-fragments

Imagine i have main activity that has viewpager. I have 2 fragments called `(F1 & F2)` that will transaction into viewpager.

Again imagine in `F1` fragment i want to set a button. When clicking on button, i want to transaction other fragment call `SUBF1` but not into `F1` fragment.

My question is here!!! Is it possible to replace SUBF1 with it's parent means F1?My idea is that i want to replace sub fragment with it's parent fragment that has been kept on fragment's container in main activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
ft.replace(R.id.details, new NewFragmentToReplace(), "NewFragmentTag"); 
ft.commit();
```

Comment: This code must executed in man activity ? right .. That's mean by callback i have to signal to activity and finally activity replace sub fragment with f1 fragment @Archana Pareta

Comment: Yes , you have to take context of activity.

Answer (score 0):

> You can save the instance of current fragment, when you are
>   navigating from one fragment to other. When user press the back
>   button,  you can open the specific fragment with the help of tag.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

 String currentTag = currentFragment.getTag();
if(currentTag.equals(res.getString(R.string.fragmentTagTest)))
            {
                currentFragment = AnotherFragment;
                replaceFragment() // integrate replace current fragment with new one. 
            }
}
```